# Groovy - java multiple conversions at the same time

Tags: java, variables, groovy

I would like to know if someone has tips on how to convert KB's variables all at the same time.

I'm reaching a Linux remote machine and retrieving at the same time 3 variables:

They are: Memory RAM total, Memory RAM used, and Memory RAM available.
The variables are received in KB's "format" but I need to display them in Gigabytes.(See the example below)

I can convert them all but only one at a time and the idea is to convert them all at the same time.

```
Memory RAM total: 5000000      // KB
Memory RAM used: 2000000       // KB
Memory RAM available: 3000000  //KB
```

This is what I did so far to convert only the Memory RAM total variable.

```
def size = 5000000 // Memory that can be converted KB MB GB AND TERABYTE

String hrSize = ""

try {
    int k = size
    double m = size / 1024 // bytes
    double g = size / 1048576 // bytes
    double t = size / 1073741824 // bytes

    DecimalFormat dec = new DecimalFormat("0.00")

    if (k > 1) {
      //If the size is more than 1kb but less than 1024 bytes, the output will be KiloBytes
        hrSize = dec.format(k).concat("KB")
    }
    if (m > 1) {
      //If the size is more than 1kb but less than 1048576 bytes, the output will be Megabytes
        hrSize = dec.format(m).concat("MB")
    }
    if (g > 1) {
      //If the size is more than 1kb and more than 1048576 but less than 1073741824 bytes, the output will be Gigabytes
        hrSize = dec.format(g).concat("GB")
    }
    if (t > 1) {
      //If the size is more than 1073741824 bytes the output will be Terabytes.
        hrSize = dec.format(t).concat("TB")
    }
} catch (Exception e) {
    println("This program ran into a problem, root cause" + e)

}
println(" The total memory from this computer is: " + hrSize)
```

Output:

```
The total memory from this computer is: 4,77GB
```

What I'm looking for?

```
The total memory from this computer is: 4,77GB
The total free from this computer is: 1,91GB
The total Available from this computer is: 2,86GB
```

Any documentation or tips?

Comment: It's unclear what you are asking about or what's the problem in your current code.

Comment: Put that code in a function and iterate your total/used/avail values over that function. If you have problems with the iteration part, then please add what you have tried and how it failed, so we can improve on it.

Comment: hello @daggett, I tried to be clear as possible, what you can't understand exactly?

Comment: Thank's for advice @cfrick

Answer (score 1):

You can improve the function by making it a loop

```
def prettySize(float size) {
    def label = ['b', 'KB', 'MB', 'GB', 'TB'].find {
        if( size < 1024 ) {
            true
        } else {
            size /= 1024 
            false
        }
    }
    "${new java.text.DecimalFormat('0.##').format(size)}$label"
}

println("The total memory from this computer is: ${prettySize(size)}")
```

Prints:

```
The total memory from this computer is: 4.77MB
```